# Facebook Graph API /{page-id}/feed not getting all posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am using /{page-id}/feed endpoint of Facebook Graph API to get the feed from a particular page.

There in the response a post from an user to the page is missing, though from facebook portal I am able to see that post on that page. As that post is visible there I can assume that is public.

Another post from the same user on a different page is also not coming in response.

Any idea on why the post is not getting returned ? also I need details about what kind of data is not supported by facebook page feed API.

Your answer will be really appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that you can see it means that it is public is a bad assumption.

Comment: Maybe that user simply disabled all app access – in which case they will be completely invisible to any app, and that includes posts they make anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

If I understood it correctly then, if the user disabled all app access, there is no way of getting those post through graph API though the post is very much visible on the page. Please confirm.